# C++, Height of Binary Tree, Instead of Checking if my subtree is empty I am checking if my subtree is a leaf node. Throws Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, height, binary-tree

**Code 1**

```
int height(Node* root) {
    if(root==NULL)
        return -1;  
    else
        return max(height(root->left),height(root->right))+1;
    }
```

**Code 2**

```
int height(Node* root) {
    if(root->left==NULL and root->right==NULL)
        return 0;  
    else
        return max(height(root->left),height(root->right))+1;
    }
```

Code 1 gives me the correct answer whereas code 2 throws segmentation fault. The logic in code 2 is correct according to me, because instead of checking an empty tree an returning -1, I am checking a leaf node and returning 0.
And can anyone explain What exactly is segmentation fault and why is this occurring in my code?

Comment: Because obviously, your `root` is a nullptr, so trying to dereference it via `root->left' causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @K.Kirsz Would you like to make that an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you are saying (namely: "Code 1 gives me the correct answer") it seems obvious that the `root` is a nullptr, so trying to dereference it via `root->left` causes undefined behavior.